# How do I need to shape my modules for dynamic import() for webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack

When trying to use [`import() with webpack`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports) using one of our components, I end up getting back an object like this instead of the module:

```
{
  __webpackChunkName: "_nteract_notebook_app_component_6bdbaebb993d75f174e800c88ff17fc7"
}
```

Example code:

```
import("@nteract/notebook-app-component").then(App => {
  // Rely on App!
  // ...
  // Except not, because we've got that strange little webpack object
})
```

Which is in steep contrast to how lodash loads, which provides the real module.

```
import("lodash").then(_ => {
  // Full blown lodash here!
})
```

---

If I look at the generated chunk file, it does have javascript in it. One thing (that might be a red herring) is that some modules have `/*! no static exports found */` in them yet have code as well. Here's the first 10 lines of the chunk:

```
$ head -n 10 dist/chunks/_nteract_notebook_app_component_6bdbaebb993d75f174e800c88ff17fc7.js
(window["webpackJsonp"] = window["webpackJsonp"] || []).push([["chunks/_nteract_notebook_app_component_6bdbaebb993d75f174e800c88ff17fc7"],{

/***/ "../../../packages/dropdown-menu/src/index.js":
/*!************************************************************************************************!*\
  !*** /Users/kylek/code/src/github.com/nteract/nteract-ext/packages/dropdown-menu/src/index.js ***!
  \************************************************************************************************/
/*! no static exports found */
/***/ (function(module, exports, __webpack_require__) {

"use strict";
```

After that it's a big chunk of `eval`ed code this is the actual module.

Comment: Can you check notebook-app-component chunk file? Does it contain any code? __webpackChunkName is provided to each dynamic webpack module, so it seems to be working. The first thing that comes to mind is that the module doesn't have any exports - so the `App` variable is empty

Comment: Yeah `dist/chunks/_nteract_notebook_app_component_6bdbaebb993d75f174e800c88ff17fc7.js` has code in it. I'll add a bit of the output to the question body.

Comment: Ok I can reproduce this with much smaller examples, even local relative files (instead of using our monorepo's scoped packages). I'm _guessing_ it's a babel transform causing the issue.

Comment: If you using `babel-preset-env` or `babel-preset-es2015` you can check out if you have `modules` option set to `false`. It should at least remove `/*! no static exports found */` comment if exports actually exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a result of using the next.js preset for babel, due to their [custom handling of `import()`](https://github.com/zeit/next.js/blob/canary/server/build/babel/plugins/handle-import.js). They create an object with the `webpackChunkName` to be used in a lookup later using their `dynamic()` function.

In order to allow dynamic imports with webpack (and babel), you need to not use the `next/babel` preset on non-next.js apps and add the `syntax-dynamic-import` plugin to your babelrc.

```
npm install --save-dev babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import
```

Example babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": ["env", "react"],
  "plugins": [
    "syntax-dynamic-import",
    "styled-jsx/babel"
  ]
}
```